# How to get mouse-move co-ordinates from the page inside the electronjs webview?

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to get the mouse co-ordinates of the mouse movement inside the electronjs webview. I am not able to get it through mouse-move event attached to webview.

I have bound the mouse-move event to webview and it gets called once. And it also gets called when you move your mouse over a section which is not part of the webview.

```
webview.addEventListener('mousemove',(e)=>{
                webview.sendInputEvent({type: 'mouseMove', x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY})
                    console.log(e,'event from mouse inside webview');
                })
```

What I am trying to get is that if I move my mouse on the page inside the webview I should be able to get the clientX and clientY values to the host.

Comment: try using this for webContents of the webview, then it will work